# http:// redirect to http//

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I got an issue with an unwanted redirection.

My Wordpress is redirect to `http//` instead of `http://`, the `:` are dissapearing.

Here is my `.htaccess` :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule> 

# END WordPress
```

If anyone have any clues on this, that would be great !

---

Edit : Ok, I got it, the Multisite functions of Wordpress was the problem. Just did a clean reinstall of the site and that's good.